# azurerm_servicebus_topic get name when using For_Each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have two variable lists, one containing a list of topic names which gets created using a for_each loop then I query the data because I need both the ID and Name.

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "topic" {
  for_each                  = local.parsed_topics
  name                      = each.key
  namespace_id              = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.namespace.id
  default_message_ttl       = each.value.default_message_ttl
  enable_batched_operations = each.value.enable_batched_operations
  max_size_in_megabytes     = 1024
  support_ordering          = each.value.support_ordering
}

data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "topic"{
  for_each                  = local.parsed_topics
  name                      = each.key
  resource_group_name       = var.resource_group_name
  namespace_name            = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.namespace.name
}
```

my second variable list contains the subscription names and attirbutes along with the associated topic name. This worked well previously in an older version of Azure RM where I didn't need the ID to create the subscription and I could use the name. I'm now trying to get this working by querying the Topic ID from a data source of the topic I created but I can't work out how to do it.

I tried the below, but I get an error because I suppose I can't query the datasource like this?

```
 resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription" {
  for_each                             = local.parsed_subscriptions
  name                                 = each.value.name
  topic_id                             = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic[index(data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic.*.name, each.value.topic_name)].id
  max_delivery_count                   = 1 
  default_message_ttl                  = each.value.default_message_ttl
  enable_batched_operations            = each.value.enable_batched_operations

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic
  ]
}
```

Error : This object does not have an attribute named "name".

**Question** :
How can I set the topic id if I only have the name of the topic ?

**Azure RM version : 3.16.0**

**Terraform : 1.2.2**

Comment: What does `local.parsed_subnets` look like?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, I don't have a `local.parsed_subnets` but the local variables I do have are just lists of data. That bit works fine here. I'm just stuggling to get the topic name using `data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic.*.name` and unsure if there is another way?

Comment: Well, if you have a `topic_name` (as it seems now you do), you can just do: `data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic[each.value.topic_name].id`. I think.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE, such a simple fix when you know how. Please post and I'll accept. I really appreciate your help have a great weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that the local variable `parsed_subscriptions` has a value for `topic_name`, the fix should be pretty simple:

```
 resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "subscription" {
  for_each                             = local.parsed_subscriptions
  name                                 = each.value.name
  topic_id                             = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic[each.value.topic_name].id
  max_delivery_count                   = 1 
  default_message_ttl                  = each.value.default_message_ttl
  enable_batched_operations            = each.value.enable_batched_operations

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_servicebus_topic.topic
  ]
}
```

Since a lot depends on how the variable is used in `for_each` was constructed [1], it might seem more complicated than it really is, but I strongly advise reading through the `for_each` documentation on keys and values.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each